# UIImagepickercontroller in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Is there any other way to open the camera in Landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here its possible to take photo in lanscape mode but preview will be showing in portrait mode,so in order to get preview in landscape mode you have to create UIImagePickerViewController using custom method using AssetsLibrary framework.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you use the Assets library for.  I think it comes with no UI, so you get to do all that yourself.  Enjoy.